# ValueAccessor can't display percentage on barchart in dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am not being able to have the percentage display over the bar chart with the code:

```
chart3barchart2 
             .width(500)
             .height(500)
             .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(['18-21', '22-26', '27-30', '31-35']))
             .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
             .margins({top: 24, left: 0, right: 10, bottom: 20})
             .colors(d3.scale.category10())
             .brushOn(false)
             .ordinalColors(['#FC6E4C'])
             .dimension(ageDim)
             .group(ageGroup)
             .valueAccessor(function (d) { return parseInt((d.value.RespondCount/ntotal2.all()[0].value.RespondCount* 100).toFixed(0),10) + "%";})
             .elasticY(true)
             .yAxisPadding('60%')
             .renderLabel(true)
             .barPadding(0.2)
             .outerPadding(0.6);

dc.renderAll("viz2");
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/koad7/65xymbrc/2/) for the whole code. 
each time I put the "%" to `.valueAccessor(function (d) { return parseInt((d.value.RespondCount/ntotal2.all()[0].value.RespondCount* 100).toFixed(0),10) + "%";})` the graph disappear altogether without showing an error in the browser console. Does someone has an idea ? thank you!

Comment: You probably want to leave `valueAccessor()` alone and use `.label()` or `.title()` to change the label or tool tip. The value accessor provides the numeric value to be used for assigning coordinates, the others provide the text.